# Optimizing of database with multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

First, some details about the website and the database structure -

With my website you can learn English words, and you can insert on each word a sentence,  an association, an image, in addition - each word has a category, sub category, group...

My database includes about 20 tables. any user who registers to my website 'add' to users table something like 4000 rows - the number of the words on my website. I have a serious problem while the user is filtering words (somthing like 'search' word but according char/s & category/s & group/s etc.. I have 9 JOINs in my sql query, and it takes something like 1 MIN to display results..

The target of JOINs - inside the table users (where each user has 4000 rows / each row = word) there are joins on this style:

```
$this->db->join('users', 'sentences.id = users.sentence_id' ,'left');
```

The same thing with associations, groups, images, binds between words etc..
The users table includes id of sentences, associations, groups.. and with the JOIN there is a connection.

I don't know what to do.. it takes too much time. maybe the problem is the structure of the database? multiple joins? maybe using indexing? but how and where? because it's necessary sometimes retrieve all the words so indexing wouldn't help.

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: How about you post the schema? Also describe the process, what goes into each table and when. Why does a single user add 4000 rows to users table -- that sounds odd?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're using that many joins, indexes will not save you (as they will not be used in joins most of the time).

There are a few things you can do.

**Schema Design**

You probably would want to reconsider your schema design/query if you need 9 joins to achieve what you are doing!

From the looks of it, it seems your your tables are very normalized, perhaps in 3rd normal form? In that case consider denormalizing your tables into a larger one to avoid joins (joins are more expensive than full table scans!). There are many online documentations on this, however there's always costs to this, as it increases development complexity and data redundancy. Also by denormalizing your tables you avoid joins and can make better use of indexes.

Also I believe MyISAM is the only storage engine in MySQL that supports FULL TEXT indexes. However it does not have transactions and have table level-locking and no MVCC, so it depends on what you need.

**Resources**

I suggest you have a read at this book [High Performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716).
A truly awesome book on tuning MySQL databases

I also suggest having a read at the official documentation on your chosen storage engine. This is significant as each storage engine is **VERY DIFFERENT**! InnoDB is completely different from MyISAM which is also completely different from PBXT. Each engine has its benefits and you will have to consider which one fits your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw out the relational schema and work out the number of operations for the queries you are running, and go from there. Most DBMS's attempt to optimise queries implicitly, but not always optimally. You should look into re-ordering the joins so that the most restrictive are carried out first. Indexes could help, and again, would require some analysis to find which attributes you are searching on.

Building databases to deal with natural language is a very challenging subject and there is a lot of research on the subject. Have you looked into Markov chains? Have you taken a step back and thought about the computational complexity of what you are trying to do? If you arrive at the same conclusion of nine joins, then it may be fair to say that the problem is not scalable enough for a real-time application.

As an aside, I believe Google App Engine's data store attempts to index attributes for you, with implicit scalability. If you're running your database on a small web server, then you may see better results deploying it with a more comprehensive DBMS. I would only look into this as a last resort, however.